# What is the use of the Hibernate @LazyCollection annotation

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading

I have 2 entities as Parent and Child as OneToMany relation as

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@IndexColumn(name = "index", base = 1)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<Child>();
// getter and setter

}
```

So here what is use of **@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)** and when does it will come in picture, like for which operation with child list, it will be beneficial ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To give you a hint, it's mainly for performance reasons, you can start reading the following links:

[Second Level Cache](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)

[Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html)

Answer (score 45):

**EXTRA** = .size() and .contains() won't initialize the whole collection

**TRUE** = initialize the whole collection on first access

**FALSE** = Eager-Loading

Comment: Will `.get(0)` initialize the whole collection?

Comment: @LakshayGarg yes

Comment: @LakshayGarg, it depends on the option you are using, EXTRA won't initialize the entire collection but will execute a query for this specific element. But it will initialize it if you instead use an iterator attached to this collection - like in stream or in for each loop. TRUE - will always initialize the whole collection.

Answer (score 30):

There's actually no reason to use `@LazyCollection`.

The `TRUE` and `FALSE` values are not needed since the same behavior can be obtained with the JPA `FetchType.LAZY` or `FetchType.EAGER`.

The `EXTRA` value has no equivalent in JPA and was designed for very large collections. When you access an `EXTRA` lazy collection for the first time, the collection is not entirely loaded, as it's usually the case with any JPA collection.

Instead, each element is fetched one by one, using a secondary `SELECT`. This might sound like an optimization, but it's not because `EXTRA` lazy collections are prone to N+1 query issues.

Note that this only works for ordered collections, either `List`(s) that are annotated with `@OrderColumn` or `Map`(s). For bags (e.g. regular `List`(s) of entities that do not preserve any certain ordering), the [`@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-extra-lazy-collections/) behaves just like any other `LAZY` collection (the collection is fetched entirely upon being accessed for the first time).

If you have a very large collection, then you should not map it at all. Instead, you should map only the `@ManyToOne` side, and, instead of a parent-side collection, you should use a paginated JPQL query.

JPQL queries are much easier to tune because you can apply any filtering criteria, and you can paginate the result set.

Comment: may I ask what is considered a very large collection?

Comment: A very large collection is a collection that takes a significant time to be fetched from the database.

Comment: You make the assumption in this answer, and in your article, that the items in the Collection are going to be iterated over. That isn't always the case. We have a couple of examples where we just want `.size()` on the Collection. With `@LazyCollection( LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA )` that's a simple `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM..`. Without the `LazyCollectionOption`, the operation becomes: select all matching rows, map them into objects, and then count the number of objects. That can be a difference of 1 or 2 seconds with a 50,000 item collection in the simple test that I ran.

Comment: You make the assumptions that mapping collections is a duty. Collections are worth mapping only when their size is rather small. Use queries for large collections so that you can paginate the. For the collection size, just use a COUNT query. It works like a charm.

Comment: @VladMihalcea No, I didn't make such assumptions. I am using a COUNT query, I've done so by annotating with `@LazyCollection( LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA )` and calling `.size()` on the mapped Collection. I prefer that over having to make a separate call to my Repository or DAO.

Comment: Once you map a collection, someone will iterate it, in which case each element will be retrieved use a separate SQL statement. That's why I,   as a Hibernate developer, don't use this Hibernate feature.

Comment: @VladMihalcea That is a risk, but can be mitigated by not making the collection accessible from the Entity. If the Entity just has `getItemCount()` and no getter for the Collection itself then it wouldn't be possible to inadvertently iterate the Collection.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Someone can still add a method in the entity to iterate the elements.

Comment: @VladMihalcea So your argument boils down to "this feature is bad because someone could use it incorrectly and experience performance issues". I don't think that's a great criteria for evaluating the usefulness of a feature, and suggest to you that there are many features in Hibernate (and many other libraries [and Java and other languages]) which have the same flaw (if you consider such an attribute a flaw).

Comment: As a top Hibernate project commiter, who worked as a Developer Advocate for the Hibernate project, yes, I'm telling everyone to avoid using this terrible "feature". But, you don't have to agree with me. It's your application after all.