# Hibernate one to many mapping annotation issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I have two tables `Team`(parent) and `Product`(child) with `TEAM_ID` column as a relationship, each team will have multiple products and each product will have single team. I have created entity classes with `@OneToMany` mapping in Team class and `@ManyToOne` in `Product` class.

I need to coverup below scenarios,

1. To save both product and team when team is new
2. Save only product if the team is already available

When i am trying to save product it tries to save team again throws constraint error.
Please help.

```
Team:

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")
public class Team implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5819170381583611288L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="teamIdSeq",sequenceName="team_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="teamIdSeq")
@Column(name="TEAM_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
private int teamId;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String teamName;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
private String teamDesc;

@Column(name="CONTACTS", nullable = false)
private String contacts;

@Column(name="APPROVER_NAME", nullable = false)
private String approverName;

@Column(name="APPROVAL_STATUS", nullable = false)
private int approvalStatus;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CREATED_ON", nullable = false)
private Date createdOn;

@Column(name="CREATED_BY", nullable = false)
private String createdBy;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="MODIFIED_ON", nullable = false)
private Date modifiedOn;

@Column(name="MODIFIED_BY", nullable = false)
private String modifiedBy;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Product> products;

//setters and getters   
}

Product:

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"PRODUCT_ID", "TEAM_ID"})})
public class Product implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5819170381583611288L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="productIdSeq", sequenceName="product_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="productIdSeq")
@Column(name="PRODUCT_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int productId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
private Team team;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String productName;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION", nullable = true)
private String productDesc;

@Column(name="APPROVER_NAME", nullable = false)
private String approverName;

@Column(name="APPROVAL_STATUS", nullable = false)
private int approvalStatus;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CREATED_ON", nullable = false)
private Date createdOn;

@Column(name="CREATED_BY", nullable = false)
private String createdBy;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="MODIFIED_ON", nullable = false)
private Date modifiedOn;

@Column(name="MODIFIED_BY", nullable = false)
private String modifiedBy;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="product")
private Set<Form> forms;
//setters and getters   
}

DAO:

@Repository
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class KMDBDAOImpl implements KMDBDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addTeam(Team team) {
    Product product = new Product(team, "BMA" + Math.random(), "UI Tool", "test", 
            1, new Date(), "test", new Date(), "test");
    Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
    products.add(product);
    team.setProducts(products);
    if(getTeam(team.getTeamName()) != null) {
        product.setTeam(getTeam(team.getTeamName()));
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(product);
    } else {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(team);
    }
}

public Team getTeam(String teamName) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Team where teamName = :name");  
    query.setString("name", "teamName");
    return (query.list().size() > 0 ? (Team) query.list().get(0) : null);
}
```

Comment: The second scenario is a simple update as data already exist, so make an update and not a new insertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time that you should set Product list on Team is when Team is a new entity. So:

```
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
products.add(product);
if(getTeam(team.getTeamName()) != null) {
    product.setTeam(getTeam(team.getTeamName()));
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(product);
} else {
    team.setProducts(products);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(team);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i give you some example code for one to many relationship please go through it and let me kn if some problem .... i have 2 tables 1.product 2.sku my condition is , one product have many sku's  ...

Product.java

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Product.class)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product" , cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Sku> listSkuOrders = new ArrayList<>();
```

Sku.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = PRODUCT_ID , nullable = false)
private Product product;
```

Comment: Thanks Y2k. As per the answer, only change is cascade type from ALL to merge table and use @LazyCollection annotation. May I know the use of @LazyCollection?

Comment: gr8 .. so please vote my answer                                                                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928402/what-is-the-use-of-the-hibernate-lazycollection-annotation